# How to use Fckeditor inasp.net website

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor

I have added fckeditor in my asp.net(vb) web site but i don't know how add pages to update at run time?
1) How to add .aspx pages in fckeditor  so that i can edit an create new pages or tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you'll create new aspx pages in fckeditor? I don't think it's possible.